# Wildcard domains with virtualhost with Apache on Mac

Tags: apache, localhost, virtualhost

I'm currently running several domains for local development

```
http://wordpress.dev
http://phpmyadmin.dev
http://projectx.dev
http://projecty.dev
...
```

Most of these projects are located in the users "Sites" directory but some are located somewhere else:

```
/Users/[username]/Sites/wordpress
/Users/[username]/Sites/phpmyadmin
/Users/[username]/Sites/projectx
/Users/[username]/OtherDirectory/projecty
```

I'm currently setup all by adding dedicate entries to the `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`

**/etc/hosts:**

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost 
fe80::1%lo0     localhost
# Virtuelle Hosts
127.0.0.1       wordpress.dev
127.0.0.1       phpmyadmin.dev
127.0.0.1       projectx.dev
....
```

**/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName [PROJECT].dev
    ServerAlias [PROJECT].dev
    DocumentRoot /Users/[username]/Sites/[PROJECT]/
    <Directory /Users/[username]/Sites/[PROJECT]/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
 ...
```

Is there a way to use some kind of wildcard settings to map the domain to a certain directory like

```
http://foo.dev =>  /Users/[username]/Sites/foo
http://bar.dev =>  /Users/[username]/Sites/bar
...
```

while keep `projecty` working (with some extra settings of course) so I only have to create a folder in `Sites` which is instantly accessible via `http://[foldername].dev`

The `[username]` can be hardcoded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`mod_vhost_alias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) and a [`VirtualDocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot)

As long as you have no VirtualHost catching `foo.dev` as a `ServerName` or `ServerAlias` you should be able to do the following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName default.dev

  VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/youruser/%-2
  ...
  ...
</VirtualHost>
```

You'll need the username to be hardcoded, though you say that's not a problem.

`%-2` in the `VirtualDocumentRoot` represents the penultimate dot-separated part of `foo.com`, i.e. `foo`. You could then have directories as you wish that map to the sites:

```
http://foo.dev =>  /Users/youruser/Sites/foo
http://bar.dev =>  /Users/youruser/Sites/bar
http://subdom.baz.dev =>  /Users/youruser/Sites/baz
```

You'll need to make sure that any additional domains you want to map in this fashion have an appropriate entry in your hosts file, or DNS if you're using that.

Comment: Can you give me a full example. This is not working: http://pastebin.com/AMM895bu

Comment: Remove the `ServerAlias` and if you have a `ServerName` of `foo.dev` anywhere else in your `vhosts.conf` you'll need to remove it. You need this configuration to be the default host to work.

Comment: doesn't work :(. I have `mod_vhost_alias` loaded, I have no foo.dev VirtualHost defined, I have `127.0.0.1 default.dev` in my `etc/hosts` file, I have a folder in Sites called "foo" with an index.html file. Anything missing?

Comment: seems I need to add `127.0.0.1 foo.dev` to `etc/hosts` to make this work. Any chance to get this "dynamic" as well

Comment: Remove `default.dev` from your hosts file too. Otherwise it might look for /Users/username/Sites/default. Comment out any other files that might be getting loaded while you're testing.

Comment: Ah, so it does work? No you can't make the host entry dynamic, your machine needs to know where to lookup `foo.dev`.

Comment: Ok, that's enough thanks. Asking for "How to use a DN Server" now, cheers

Comment: Unfortunately subfolders are not working with this (eg `http://foo.dev/subfolder`) Please advice!

Comment: Can you elaborate on "not working"? Are you getting an error?

Comment: sorry, not (real) subdirectories but my .htaccess doesn't work. It should redirect all to the index.php

Comment: You need to ask a new question for this, it's a separate subject. If you link to it I'll be happy to help. Note that you'll now need a `.htaccess` per virtual domain root. Anything a level up won't be accessible. If you want a basic `RewriteRule` for all virtual sites, put it in the `VirtualHost` config itself.

Comment: yes this should be a new question, the htaccess is actually in the project folder, I'll post a link if the question has been posted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Here's the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26652896/htaccess-doesnt-work-on-virtualhost

Answer (score 0):

In order to accomplish what you need, you can configure a dynamically configured mass virtual host.

To have it you should add something like the following to your `httpd.conf` file:

```
# get the server name from the Host: header
UseCanonicalName Off

# this log format can be split per-virtual-host based on the first field
LogFormat "%V %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %s %b" vcommon
CustomLog logs/access_log vcommon

# include the server name in the filenames used to satisfy requests
VirtualDocumentRoot /www/hosts/%0/docs
VirtualScriptAlias /www/hosts/%0/cgi-bin
```

That would do the same as the following:

```
NameVirtualHost 111.22.33.44
<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44>
    ServerName www.customer-1.com
    DocumentRoot /www/hosts/www.customer-1.com/docs
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /www/hosts/www.customer-1.com/cgi-bin
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44>
    ServerName www.customer-2.com
    DocumentRoot /www/hosts/www.customer-2.com/docs
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /www/hosts/www.customer-2.com/cgi-bin
</VirtualHost>
# blah blah blah
<VirtualHost 111.22.33.44>
    ServerName www.customer-N.com
    DocumentRoot /www/hosts/www.customer-N.com/docs
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /www/hosts/www.customer-N.com/cgi-bin
</VirtualHost>
```

For more details on this, check [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html)