# .htaccess doesn't work on VirtualHost

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Since I've setup a [wildcard VirtualHost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575276/wildcard-domains-with-virtualhost-with-apache-on-mac) my htaccess files does not work anymore

The **http-vhosts.conf**

```
NameVirtualHost *

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default.dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/[UserName]/Sites/%-2
    <Directory /Users/[UserName]/Sites/%-2>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

the **.htaccess** (WordPress default)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I can access `http://wordpress.dev` and also the backend but not a page like `http://wordpress.dev/page` (causes a 404 error).
I can set the permalink structure to default but I would like to have "nice URLs"

I'm on a local development environment on Mac OS X 10.10 with Apache 2.4

Comment: I'm assuming the .htaccess you describe lives at `/Users/[UserName]/Sites/wordpress/.htaccess` and `/Users/[UserName]/Sites/wordpress/index.php` also exists?

Comment: yes, it worked before when I manually added each virtual host separately

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `VirtualHost` definition to:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName default.dev
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/[UserName]/Sites/%-2
    <Directory /Users/[UserName]/Sites>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

i.e, root the directory definition to Sites, not to the virtual directory.

Comment: That's the one! Thanks so much for your time (again).