# Domain and subdomain wildcards on Apache as dynamic subfolders

Tags: apache, subdomain, wildcard

I'm creating website builder like `weebly` and `wix` format. I would like to dynamic subfolders. For example:

```
domain.com        /public_html/sites/domain.com/

sub1.root.com     /public_html/sites/sub1/

test.com          /public_html/sites/test.com/

sub2.root.com     /public_html/sites/sub2/
```

I can do only `static` with following and forced me to add one by one whole websites.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/public_html/sites/domain.com"
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```

How can i do dynamic both domains that client owner and subdomains that i'll give user.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26575276/wildcard-domains-with-virtualhost-with-apache-on-mac/26636481

Comment: @arco444 This is only about subdomain. I need dynamic `ServerName` as domain too. I couldnt catch domains.

Comment: OK. I don't think you'll get away with sharing a `VirtualHost` for a top level domain. You'd need 3 here, one for `domain.com`, `test.com` and `root.com`

Comment: @arco444 What can i do for host domains and subdomains on my subfolders? I didnt know anything about wildcards.

Answer (score 12):

For dynamic domain name configuration based on the names of folders you create in
 `/public_html/sites/`, you can use the [`ServerAlias`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) and [`VirtualDocumentRoot`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot) directives.

Add something like this in your apache virtualhost configuration file:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ...
    ServerAlias *
    VirtualDocumentRoot /public_html/sites/%0
    ...
</VirtualHost>
```

To understand why **%0** is used, consider the domain `m.rate.movies.net` split into parts

```
Index:             %1      %2      %3       %4
Domain:             m     rate    movies    net
Negative Index:    %-4     %-3     %-2      %-1
```

The one I chose to use, `%0` represents the entire domain name - `m.rate.movies.net`. This allows you to support domain names that can have varying number of parts separated by dots. This makes sub-directories created inside `/public_html/sites/` be the document root for any domain name pointed to your server's IP.

```
  /public_html/sites/domain.com        --> http://domain.com/
  /public_html/sites/blog.writers.org  --> http://blog.writers.org/
  /public_html/sites/m.rate.movies.net --> http://m.rate.movies.net/
```

---

If you used something like `VirtualDocumentRoot /public_html/sites/%1`

You will have to create the sub-directories this way

```
  /public_html/sites/domain   --> http://domain.com/
  /public_html/sites/blog     --> http://blog.writers.org/
  /public_html/sites/m        --> http://m.rate.movies.net/
```

---

You can also use a combination: `VirtualDocumentRoot /public_html/sites/%-2\.%-1`

```
  /public_html/sites/domain.com   --> http://domain.com/
  /public_html/sites/writers.org  --> http://blog.writers.org/
  /public_html/sites/movies.net   --> http://m.rate.movies.net/
```

---

Yet another way: `VirtualDocumentRoot /public_html/sites/%-1/%-2/`

```
  /public_html/sites/com/domain   --> http://domain.com/
  /public_html/sites/org/writers  --> http://blog.writers.org/
  /public_html/sites/net/movies   --> http://m.rate.movies.net/
```

---

With these setup, you won't have to edit the virtual host configuration every time you add a new domain. You won't be able to use separate log files for each domain, but for that, you can use a [custom log](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_log_config.html#customlog) format that includes the host name.